# Wordpress WP_Query compare only Month part of meta_query key

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

i have been trying to use wordpress wp_query method, but my case is specific.

I need to select all product of the current month so here is my code

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',

    'meta_query' => array(
            'Relation' => 'AND',
    array(
            'key'     => 'wpcf-product_status',
            'value'   => 'valid',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    array(
            'key'     => 'wpcf-product-start_date',
            'compare' => '=',

            'date_query' => array(
                array(
                        'month'      => date('m'),
                        'compare'   => '=',
                ),              
        ),
    ),
    ),
);
// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I can not get the exact result.
how is it possible to test only the date MONTH like it is done is SQL (`WHERE MONTH(wpcf-product-start_date) = MONTH(NOW())`)

any idea please?

Comment: What's the format of your  `wpcf-product-start_date` custom field? You can't use `date_query` on custom fields.

Comment: the format is TIMESTAMP

Comment: Can you save the custom field in another format?

Comment: are you looking for a given month in a given year (Y-m)?  if that's the case then we can find the timestamp period for the given Y-m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here are few additional options:

1. If you want to filter a given *month* in a given *year*, you can just calculate the *timestamp* period for that month and use the corresponding *compare operators* of the meta query to filter it.
2. You might want to consider changing the format of the `wpcf-product-start_date` custom field values, to `Y-m-d`, `Y-m` or `m`, depending of your needs.
3. You could use the `{added,updated,deleted}_post_meta` hooks (see for example this [fine answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/how-to-hook-update-post-meta-and-delete-post-meta)) to automatically save a new custom field, containing the month number calculated from the `wpcf-product-start_date` timestamp. For example:

   ```
   add_action( 'added_post_meta',   'b2e_update_post_meta', 10, 4 );
   add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'b2e_update_post_meta', 10, 4 );

   function b2e_update_post_meta( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
   {
       if ( 'wpcf-product-start-date' === $meta_key )
       {
           // avoid infinite loop
          remove_action( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );            

          // add/update the corresponding month value
          update_post_meta( $post_id, 
                            'wpcf-product-start-month', 
                            date( 'n', $meta_value ) 
          );
       }
   }

   add_action( 'deleted_post_meta', 'b2e_delete_post_meta', 10, 4 );

   function b2e_delete_post_meta( $deleted_meta_ids, $post_id, $meta_key,
                                  $only_delete_these_meta_values )
   {
       if ( 'wpcf-product-start-date' === $meta_key )
       {
           // avoid infinite loop
           remove_action( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );            

          // delete the corresponding month key        
           delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-product-start-month' );
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can use `wpcf-product-start-month` in your meta-query.

   Notice that I used `wpcf-product-start-date` here. Somehow this didn't triggered for the custom field with the meta-key `wpcf-product-start_date`. But let me know if you have problems with this.
4. If you are *adventurous* you can play with the `posts_where` filter:

   ```
   $args = array(
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'post_type'      => 'product',
       'meta_query'     => array(
           'relation'    => 'AND',
           array(
               'key'     => 'wpcf-product_status',
               'value'   => 'valid',
               'compare' => '='
           ),
           array(
               'key'     => 'wpcf-product-start_date',
               'compare' => '=',
               'value'   => 'replace_me',
           ),
       ),
   );

   add_filter( 'posts_where', 'b2e_posts_where' );
   $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'b2e_posts_where' );
   ```

   where

   ```
   function b2e_posts_where( $where )
   {
       $month = 3; // Edit this value

       if( FALSE !== stripos( $where, 'replace_me' ) )
       {
           $from  = "CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'replace_me'";
           $to    = "MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME( 1 * mt1.meta_value ) ) = $month 
                     AND YEAR( FROM_UNIXTIME( 1 * mt1.meta_value ) ) > 1970 ";
           $where = str_ireplace( $from, $to, $where );
       }
       return $where;
   }
   ```

   Notice that this assumes that the `replace_me` value is in the *second* meta query array item.
   The table names can change if you reorder the array items (e.g. `wp_postmeta, mt1, ...` ). It's possible to find the 
   correct table name automatically, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. And be sure that 'wpcf-product-start_date' has got the same format of 'date('m')' :)

```
$m = date('m');
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',

    'meta_query' => array(
            'Relation' => 'AND',
    array(
            'key'     => 'wpcf-product_status',
            'value'   => 'valid',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    array(
            'key'     => 'wpcf-product-start_date',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value'   => '$m'    
        ),
    ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Actually wpcf-product-start_date is saved as timestamp

Comment: This complicates things. Is the month in the timestamp ALWAYS the same of product's publication? If yes http://pastebin.com/iCJ21kCi

Comment: i think the best solution is to get ALL products with wp_qyery then filter in php in the loop

Answer (score 0):

OR...

You can get the month start and month end as a timestamp and use a 'BETWEEN' meta compare:

eg.

```
$year = date('Y'); $month = date('m')
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
$month_start = strtotime($year .  '-' . $month . '-1 00:00:00');
$month_end = strtotime($year .  '-' . $month . '-' . $days_in_month . ' 23:59:59');

$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'wpcf-product-start_date',
        'value' => array(
             $month_start,
             $month_end
        ),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
);
```

or...

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array (
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-product-start_date',
            'value' => $month_start,
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-product-start_date',
            'value' => $month_end,
            'compare' => '<='
        )
    )
)
```